# JavaFX 8 application requires system reboot before working

Tags: javafx-8

I created a JavaFX/1.8.0_60 app on Windows 7 64 bit with MSI/EXE native installers.  The app installs correctly system-msi/user-exe level but when clicking desktop shortcut my application window is sometimes blank and I need to reboot to make it work.

Running native distributions with debug settings indicates some missing prism info/loading:

```
jvmArgs = ['-verbose:class']
systemProperties = ['javafx.verbose':'true', 'prism.verbose':'true']
```

Before reboot - window is blank
(System.out)

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
QLoading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
```

(System.err)

```
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\msvcr120.dll from relative path
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\msvcp120.dll from relative path
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\prism_d3d.dll from relative path
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
JavaFX: using com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\glass.dll from relative path
 vsync: true vpipe: true
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\javafx_font.dll from relative path
```

After reboot - window is correct
(System.out)

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
OS Information:
    Windows 7 build 7601
D3D Driver Information:
    Intel(R) HD Graphics
    \\.\DISPLAY1
    Driver igdumd64.dll, version 8.15.10.2752
    Pixel Shader version 3.0
    Device : ven_8086, dev_0102, subsys_307017AA
    Max Multisamples supported: 4
Loading Prism common native library ...
    succeeded.
```

(System.err)

```
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\msvcr120.dll from relative path
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\msvcp120.dll from relative path
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\prism_d3d.dll from relative path
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
JavaFX: using com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\glass.dll from relative path
Maximum supported texture size: 8192
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
 vsync: true vpipe: true
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\javafx_font.dll from relative path
Loaded C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\myapp\runtime\lib\ext\..\..\bin\prism_common.dll from relative path
```

Any ideas why graphics/prism wont load and how to diagnose further on Windows 7 so that I don't need to reboot is appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Might have something to do with your graphics drivers, have you checked they are up2date?